# How to enable group policy toggle button using powershell or cmd

Tags: powershell, cmd, regedit, group-policy

I am trying to automate sever setup of a windows 2019 server using userdata. I need to update the local group policy settings.

The specific group policy i want to enable is "Set time limit for disconnected sessions"

[image]

How can i enable this 'local' group policy for a vm using powershell or bash or even Regedit.

I have tried but i cant seem to get it be in an "enabled" state.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this Registry Edit.

You can access this [registry key](https://www.windows-security.org/8c3304092f62695729074b114e454ae4/set-time-limit-for-disconnected-sessions) in Powershell or Bash.

More information [here.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/500ca129-de8e-4439-9494-f9f239be4071/session-time-limits-in-gpo-are-not-applying-on-some-rdd-session-hosts?forum=winserverTS)

```
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services" /v MaxDisconnectionTime /t REG_DWORD /d 5000 /f
```

Comment: The command runs successfully. However, it still shows as not configured when I go back into group policy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, its the same registry key but using Powershell to set.

```
Set-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services" -Name MaxDisconnectionTime -Type REG_DWORD -Value 900000
```

The value is in ms, this would set it to 15 minutes.

https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.TerminalServer::TS_SESSIONS_Disconnected_Timeout_2

After you run that, restart the device and the settings should be updated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to directly configure the local group policy using PowerShell.

When configured, the GPO sets a registry key and value.
It's not bi-directional where you can set the registry key and then the GPO is configured.

You can use Microsoft's tool [LGPO.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/secguide/lgpo-exe-local-group-policy-object-utility-v1-0) to export the policy settings from a computer you've configured, and then use PowerShell to import those settings to your new computer.